# Worker Threads and Using Multple Messages Queue Software? Good Idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

Problem: I have a program that will do a lot of post-processing on a file and then sending it ANOTHER web-service for more processing.  Does my design smell and is this the right way to ‘tackle a problem’

1. Rails Accepts file and kicks off a resque_job  to do work
2. The resque job will sends work via REST to another web-service cluster(very slow.. does MORE work) && places the task to be monitored in a monitor_queue  within Rabbit MQ for completion . The Resque job will not wait another-webservice to complete task. It exits

There are some smell issues in my design, perhaps gut reactions that could be misguided?

- Is it good design to have TWO message queues. The rational is that Rabbit_MQ has a built in method for creating worker_queues (they even give sample code). Resque_Job uses redis, and seems to be the accepted method of having ‘delayed jobs’ with Rails.
- What I like about RabbitMQ: It has round-robin tasking  abilities (so all threats get tasked) , and guarantees work will not be removed from a QUEUE without a message acknowledgement.
- Resque seems to primary suggested solution for launching delayed_jobs within Rails.

Followup: When performing the polling, I was thinking a simple worker_queue of just iterating through the entire queue with seperate 'workers' makes the most sense? Do you agree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bad design. It's a type of Service Oriented Architecture, and even though you have separate queuing systems, they're completely separate applications and would only communicate through a specific interface, which has some pros and cons. I didn't quite understand the reasoning for using RabbitMQ, though. Also, a lot of new apps seem to be using Sidekiq; IMHO it is superior in every way to Resque.